# How to make variables within a function available globally

Tags: javascript

How would I make the variables within the function available in the global scope without removing them from the function and so they are logged in the console?

```
function foo(){
  var one = 1;
  var two = 2; 
}

foo();
console.log(one, two);
```

Comment: You can't. They are local.

Comment: well you can actually

Comment: `var` created local variables. So don't use `var`.

Comment: @RaymondChen "So don't use var." is actually not that good advice. It is better to specify namespace explicitly to avoid pollution. Yet to do not forget about "use strict" mode.

Comment: What you are asking can be achieved, and several have showed options, however, what you are asking is a really bad idea, and depending what you are really wanting to do, there's probably a much better way to do it

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want the variables to be local, or global? You can't have both. If they are declared "within the function", then they are local, and cannot be accessed globally. If there are declared globally, then they are not "within the function" (other than being set there). Which is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the variables outside of the function, you can declare them outside of it. The function will still have access to be able to assign to them.

```js
var one, two;

function foo(){
  one = 1;
  two = 2; 
}

foo();
console.log(one, two);
```

Or, if you just need the values, you can have the function return them.

```js
function foo(){
  var one = 1;
  var two = 2;
  return { one: one, two: two };
}

var result = foo();
console.log(result.one, result.two);
```

Answer (score 1):

solution :

```
function foo(){ 
  one = 1; 
  two = 2;
}

foo(); 
console.log(one, two);
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/xmm041df/1/

Explanation:

When you use var you are declaring variable for that scope. in your case the function scope.

However when not specifying a scope it will default to the outermost scope. in our case window.

This is not advised though and pollutes the main namespace which is never a good idea.

Comment: Note: in node.js this will also allow you to declare things that escape module scope.

Comment: In many environments, this will result in a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: @torazaburo: Only in strict mode

Comment: If that script is run in "use strict" mode it will produce runtime error.

Comment: @torazaburo it will only have a referenceError in strict mode But thanks for the downvote for the first person who posted this answer and got copied by 5 others.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this is not a very good answer. The OP has said "*how would I make the variables **within the function** available in the global scope **without removing them from the function***. so it's a reasonable presumption that he **doesn't** want to make them global, either explicitly or implicitly. I believe the correct answer is "variables cannot be accessed outside their scope". Much of the world runs in strict mode these days (and should if it doesn't).

Comment: @torazaburo he specifically asked `available in the global scope` so my answer was right on the money, and i also gave him the proper warnings against it.

Comment: @NetaMeta Any reasonable reading of his question ends up asking "how can I access a local variable from the global scope?". And the answer is, you can't, that why it's called "local".

Comment: @torazaburo: That the variables would be process-global available to all modules even those that did not require your module. I had to do something like this once (don't ask, it was messy)

Comment: @torazaburo please read the op's question - You want to try an supernaturally understand thing he said that's your deal, but he asked specifically `How would I make the variables within the function available in the global scope` whichis possible and in my answer.

Comment: @slebetman Actually, that's not correct. A variable declared in a module, either explicitly or implicitly, is **not** available to all modules.

Comment: @torazaburo actually, the OP seems to put more emphasis on having them global than local, it almost looks like he made them local because he  didn't know how to access global variables from a function?  who knows..... it's very ambiguous

Comment: The OP's question is something like, "I have a black cat. Can it also be white?".

Comment: @KeithNicholas Yes, you're right, I added a request for clarification in a comment on the question.

Comment: we are humans, not compilers, sometimes new people ask what seems like impossible questions because they don't know the proper way to phrase things.  OP basically asked how to access the variables declared in foo in the global namespace.   It's like he got a black cat, but wants a white one, and thinks maybe there's some magic that does that :)

Comment: @torazaburo: No. Your assumption is not correct. I thought that was how it works too until I tried it.

Comment: @torazaburo: I believe slebetmans point is that variables which are *not* declared will escape the module scope, because assignments create global-object properties in sloppy mode.

Answer (score 0):

Function is an object so you can do for example this:

```
function foo(){
  foo.one = 1;
  foo.two = 2; 
}

foo();
console.log(foo.one, foo.two);
```

Or if you want those variables to be placed in global namespace then this:

```
function foo(){
  window.one = 1; // if in browser
  window.two = 2; 
}

foo();
console.log(one, two);
```

UPDATE: `window.` is used there to avoid runtime errors in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Comment: Any reason you've added `window.` ?

Comment: @NetaMeta: Because it's a reference error otherwise. You're using strict mode, right?

Comment: @Bergi - you assume that someone that ask a question like that even know what strict mode to use it .. hmm...

Comment: @NetaMeta: No, I'm assuming nothing about the OP. He might unwittingly use it, or he might not; in any case one *should* always use strict mode and writing code the violates strict mode rules is despised for good reason.

Comment: @Bergi if that is the case then doing any of this is a bad idea, the attempt of having local variables on global namespace is a bad idea in general and we should not give him any answer at all.

Comment: @NetaMeta roughly equivalent to saying, this person asking about the gun doesn't know what a gun lock is, so I won't bother to tell him about it or why he should use it.

Comment: @torazaburo nope this analogy isn't far from correct, you'll be closer had you said something like the guy bought a gun and trying to shot  himself in the head and you tell him he should get closer to get better results. - the whole idea of buying a gun and shorting your self in the head is bad.

Comment: My analogy of the gun lock was meant to refer to use of strict mode, not the concept of global variables.

Comment: @torazaburo, i understood your analogy you did not understand mine. using strict mode or not he is still doing a big no no with the variable, In my opinion a lot worst then strict mode, so having him add window. would be just like telling him your doing something wrong but hey here is how you'll do it better.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a value to a variable that has not been declared, it will automatically become a GLOBAL variable.

```
// code here can use carName

function myFunction() {
    carName = "Volvo";

    // code here can use carName

}
```

Example taken from: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: …but only in sloppy mode, which you should not use.

Answer (score 0):

Sample javascript code for your problem :

```
<script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript">
  TestFunction();

function TestFunction()
{
    testVariableOne ="Value1"; 
    testVariableSeond = 2; 
    FunctionToTestGlobalVariables(this);
};

function FunctionToTestGlobalVariables(callback)
{
   alert("FirstGlobalVariable" + callback.testVariableOne);
   alert("SecondGlobalVariable"+ callback.testVariableSeond); 

    // Or use like this since they are global now 
  //alert("FirstGlobalVariable" + testVariableOne);
  //alert("SecondGlobalVariable"+ testVariableSeond); 
}; 

</script>
```

Study scope of function variables from the below link. 
Reference : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

var limits the scope to the function in which it is used. So dont use var.

Comment: What does `language="javascript" ` mean ?

Comment: @c-smile : this is deprecated in the current html standards. It was used previously to denote your scripting language.

Comment: If it is deprecated, why did you include it in your answer? `text="type/javascript"` is also not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

use window object to set the property.

```
function foo()
{
   window.one = 1;
   window.two = 2; 
}

foo();
console.log(one, two);
```